# Updating views of sub Activities of TabActivity from background process

Tags: android, view, android-activity, tabactivity

I am using a `TabActivity (Main)` with 3 TabSpecs
I am using Intents for the content of the 3 Tabs
`TabA`, `TabB`, `TabC` for example.

All these tab activities use common data that is stored in `SharedPreferences`

In the `Main` `TabActivity` I have an options menu which has a refresh option.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.refresh_menu:
        new updateCommonDataFromWeb().execute();

    ...
    }
}
```

this refresh uses an `AsyncTask` (updateCommonDataFromWeb) to reload the common data from the web.

I need a way to tell the 3 tab activities to refresh their views and rebuild their content from the newly downloaded data.

When the tab activities are first created they load the data from `SharedPreferences` like so:

```
public class TabA extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taba);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(this.getString(R.string.prefs_name), 0);
        String usage_data = prefs.getString("common_data", "");
    }
}
```

I thought about making a common method on each of the tab activities
like.... `reloadViewData()`

I thought maybe I could use the activity manager from the `Main` `TabActivity` to get the activity of the current tab like so:

```
String tabTag = tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag);
# then call the reloadData() method of the tab activity
activity.reloadViewData();
```

Unfortunately i cant get this approach to work, whilst `activity` is the correct instance its an `Activity` instead of a `TabA`,`TabB` or `TabC`

Maybe i've completely taken the wrong approach to the whole thing.

I have also read alot about not using Activities for tab content instead using views.
However I dont know what view to use to replace my `<RelativeLayout />` as i cant use my R.layout.* as views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `common_data` in the `sharedPreferences` you can also implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the Activites and check for `key.equals("common_data")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Activity and make all your child activities to inherit from your extended activity, as this way you will implement the same code (service handling) in 1 activity(the parent).

```
Activity -> MyParentActivity -> MyChildActivity1
```

This way you will be able to cast all your child activities to MyParentActivity and run your custom method (you want to be implemented)